# convert rows to columns using sed in shell

Tags: shell

Hi I am having file with below 7 rows (some of the rows having single space and tab space in starting)

> aass
>   akjbjbj
>   akkbhh
>   bkkbb
>   bblkk
>   bklkkml
>   cvbblk

I want the final outpput as:

> aass|akjbjbj|akkbhh|bkkbb|bblkk|bklkkml|cvbblk

Answer (score 1):

```
head -c -1 | tr '\n' '|'
```

You need only need `head` if the text ends with a newline (which is normal for regular text files).